# Reset Gcloud Windows Instance Gateway or Network Configuration

Tags: virtual-machine, gcloud

I made a big mistake and changed the gateway value in the windows network configuration, now I cant connect to my Windows server instance anymore.

how can I reset the network configuration inside the machine from the google console? THANKS THIS WILL SAVE MY LIFE

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the network configuration using a startup script.

Go to your server configuration, metadata and enter these values:

For the metadata variable:

**windows-startup-script-cmd**

For its value:

**netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp**

reset the server and it will reconfigure to DHCP mode.